# Dictionary sometimes featuring with multiple keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda, key-value

I have a pandas data frame, and I would like to make a new column/s based on the dictionary values.

Here is my df and dictionary:

```
data = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Count'])

dictionary = {'One':'Red', 'Two':['Red', 'Blue'], 'Three':'Green','Four':['Green','Red', 'Blue']}
```

This is the result I would like to achieve,

[image]

Preferably with blank fields instead of **None** values, does anybody know a way?

I tried the below:

```
df = df = pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) for k, v in dictionary.items()])
df.columns = ['name'] + [f'n{x}' for x in df.columns[1:]]
df
```

However, for keys that do not have multiple values, it seems to split the actual string per letter over the columns like so:
[image]

A solution where it maps the values to one columns separated with a delimiter (,) would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lists in values of dictionary, so need `if-else` statement for prevent unpack strings by `*`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) 
                   if isinstance(v, list) 
                   else (k, v) for k, v in dictionary.items()])
df.columns = ['name'] + [f'n{x}' for x in df.columns[1:]]
print (df)
    name     n1    n2    n3
0    One    Red  None  None
1    Two    Red  Blue  None
2  Three  Green  None  None
3   Four  Green   Red  Blue
```

**Details**:

```
print (((*'Red', )))
('R', 'e', 'd')

print (((*['Red', 'Blue'], )))
('Red', 'Blue')
```

> Preferably with blank fields instead of None values, does anybody know a way?

Add [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) 
                   if isinstance(v, list) 
                   else (k, v) 
                   for k, v in dictionary.items()]).fillna('')
df.columns = ['name'] + [f'n{x}' for x in df.columns[1:]]
print (df)
    name     n1    n2    n3
0    One    Red            
1    Two    Red  Blue      
2  Three  Green            
3   Four  Green   Red  Blue
```

If same indices and number of rows use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

If original `df_orig` has different like default `RangeIndex` add `index=df_orig.index` to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) 
                   if isinstance(v, list) 
                   else (k, v) 
                   for k, v in dictionary.items()], index=df_orig.index).fillna('')
df.columns = ['name'] + [f'n{x}' for x in df.columns[1:]]

df = df_orig.join(df)
```

If need merge by `name` column by left join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = df_orig.merge(df, on='name', how='left')
```

Comment: Thank You, this has been really helpful, is there any way to add these values as separate columns, but using the main df which has many other columns that need to be kept? As we'd just been making this as a new df from the dictionary

Comment: @Nairda123 - Original DataFrame has same number of rows like this new? Or need merge by `name` column by original DataFrame?

Comment: @Nairda123 - Both solutions added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check whether or not `v` a `list` and ensure you are not unpacking the strings as characters:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) if isinstance(v, list) else (k, v)
                   for k, v in dictionary.items()])
df.columns = ['name'] + [f'n{x}' for x in df.columns[1:]]
```

Output:

```
    name     n1    n2    n3
0    One    Red  None  None
1    Two    Red  Blue  None
2  Three  Green  None  None
3   Four  Green   Red  Blue
```

#### joining to another dataframe

Using [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) depending on whether you want to combine based on the index or the "name" column:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) if isinstance(v, list) else (k, v)
                   for k, v in dictionary.items()]
                   ).fillna('')
df2.columns = ['name'] + [f'n{x}' for x in df.columns[1:]]

# if same index 
out = df.join(df2)

# Or merging on a common column
out = df.merge(df2, on='name', how='left')
```

Output:

```
  original   name     n1    n2    n3
0        A    One    Red            
1        B    Two    Red  Blue      
2        C  Three  Green            
3        D   Four  Green   Red  Blue
```

Used `df`:

```
  original   name
0        A    One       
1        B    Two      
2        C  Three            
3        D   Four
```

Comment: I added the required code to join/merge to another dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame.from_records([[x, dictionary[x]] for x in dictionary])[1]
       .apply(pd.Series))

df2.columns = [f'Color{x+1}' for x in df2.columns]

pd.concat([df['Count'], df2], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Count Color1 Color2 Color3
0    One    Red    NaN    NaN
1    Two    Red   Blue    NaN
2  Three  Green    NaN    NaN
3   Four  Green    Red   Blue
```